# Bootstrap Tab from URL

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to reach a specific section of a page coming from another page through a link like `<a href="someplace/#loctn">a link</a>`  I can reach the page with the right address in the Browser's URL but what i don´t see is the right section.

I've got a short peace of the final page here:

```
<!--Here we have a Bootstrap's Nav Tab:-->

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
     <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="user-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#user" role="tab" aria-controls="user" aria-selected="true">
         User
        </a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="loctn-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#loctn" role="tab" aria-controls="loctn" aria-selected="false">
             Location
        </a>
     </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="user" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="user-tab">
        "First section, which is being shown every time i get the url"
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="loctn" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="loctn-tab">
         "Second section, which i would like to reach but i can't..."
     </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: is the content rendered server-side or client-side?

Comment: I believe the content is being rendered Client-side.

Comment: that's the problem then - browser looks for the `#loctn` element when the page is initially loaded, but the element gets rendered afterwards.

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: yes - since you know what's the root cause of the problem, google for solution. You're not the first person encountering this issue.